# Using RewriteCond with %{REQUEST_URI} for mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like the URL:

```
http://domain.com/category/subcategory/title
```

To point to:

```
http://domain.com/posts/category/subcategory/title.php
```

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^.+
#RewriteCond post/%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ post/$1.php [L]
```

This works however when I uncomment the line above it does not work.

I have tried:

```
RewriteCond /post/%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteCond post/%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteCond post%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
```

None of these work. What am I doing wrong?

Also is there an easy way to debug these rules? Like console logging variables or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-f` check requires full filesystem path. You can do this using `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` variable:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/post/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ post/$1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you mean the line

```
RewriteCond post/%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
```

[`REQUEST_URI`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) is

> The path component of the requested URI, such as "/index.html".

`post/%{REQUEST_URI}.php` is then some relative path from where the Apache web server is running. This might be the root directory `/`, Apache's configuration directory `/etc/apache2`, its document root `/var/www/html`, or even `/var/tmp`, or anything else.

- `/post/%{REQUEST_URI}.php`
- `/etc/apache2/post/%{REQUEST_URI}.php`
- `/var/www/html/post/%{REQUEST_URI}.php`
- `/var/tmp/post/%{REQUEST_URI}.php`
- `/home/olaf/post/%{REQUEST_URI}.php`

As you see, you can't really know what file Apache will look at. And Apache might find a file at this place, or it may not. To be sure, you must provide an absolute path as [@anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38999262/1741542) already suggested.